# Compare two sentences and identify wrong words in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to compare two sentences. Here is the example:

Correct: Experts believe industrial development will help the economy. 
Given: Xperts does believe that development won't economy.

Expected Output:

**Experts** *Xperts* *does* believe **industrial** *that* development **will** *won't* **help** **the** economy.

I have tried to compare string by splitting the both words and checking them.

```
let given= "Xperts does believe that development won't economy.";
let correct= "Experts believe industrial development will help the economy.";

function checkSentence(given,correct){
    let final='';
        for(i=0; i<given.length; i++){
            if(given[i].trim()==correct[i].trim()){
                final += given[i]+' ';
            }else{
                final += "<i>given[i]</i> <b>correct[i]</b>";
            }
        }
        return final;
}
```

Comment: Check out https://github.com/kpdecker/jsdiff

Comment: I don't understand this. If this is just a "replace", why not `if given.match(/Xperts does believe that development won't economy/) given = correct`? Or do you want to write a sentence by a given sentence?

Comment: You're not splitting the sentences into words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would solve the problem recursively with the following steps:

1. Try to find the closest matching word in each sentence
2. If match found: Split each sentence at the matching word and run the same function on each side
3. If no match found: Both sentences have nothing in common and you can return each sentence formatted in the way you want

*Note: I start and try to find the longest matching word because those are most indicative of sentence structure rather than searching for 'it' and 'and'*

```js
const correct= "Experts believe industrial development will help the economy.";
const given= "Xperts does believe development that won't economy.";

const correctArray = correct.split(" ")
const givenArray = given.split(" ")

// Returns [correctIndex, givenIndex] if match found or [-1, -1] if no match found
function findIndexOfLongestMatchingWord(correctArray, givenArray) {

  // Create an array of word length and its index for the correct word array 
  const correctWordLengthIndexArray = correctArray.map((word, index) => [word.length, index]).sort(([length1, index1], [length2, index2]) => length2 - length1)

  for(let matchingIndex = 0; matchingIndex < correctArray.length; matchingIndex++) {
    
    const correctArrayIndex = correctWordLengthIndexArray[matchingIndex][1]
    const correctArrayWord = correctArray[correctArrayIndex]
    const foundIndexOfGivenWord = givenArray.findIndex(givenWord => givenWord === correctArrayWord)

    if(foundIndexOfGivenWord != -1) return [correctArrayIndex, foundIndexOfGivenWord];
  }

  return [-1,-1]
}

function formatCorrectArray(correctArray) {
  return correctArray.length == 0 ? "" : `<b>${correctArray.join(" ")}</b>`
}

function formatGivenArray(givenArray) {
  return givenArray.length == 0 ? "" : `<i>${givenArray.join(" ")}</i>`
}


function findDifferenceRecursively(correctArray, givenArray) {

  // If either array empty there is nothing to compare, return each one formatted
  if(correctArray.length == 0 || givenArray.length == 0) {
    return formatCorrectArray(correctArray) + formatGivenArray(givenArray)
  }

  const [correctIndex, givenIndex] = findIndexOfLongestMatchingWord(correctArray, givenArray);

  if (correctIndex != -1) {
    // Split each string at their index and run find difference on each side of the indexes;
    const leftCorrect = correctArray.slice(0, correctIndex)
    const rightCorrect = correctArray.slice(correctIndex + 1)

    const leftGiven = givenArray.slice(0, givenIndex)
    const rightGiven = givenArray.slice(givenIndex + 1)

    // Run function on words on each side
    return findDifferenceRecursively(leftCorrect, leftGiven) + ` ${correctArray[correctIndex]} ` + findDifferenceRecursively(rightCorrect, rightGiven)
  } else {
    return formatCorrectArray(correctArray) + formatGivenArray(givenArray)
  }
}

const result = findDifferenceRecursively(correctArray, givenArray)

// Returns "<b>Experts</b><i>Xperts does</i> believe <b>industrial</b> development <b>will help the</b><i>that won't</i> economy. "
console.log(result)
```